# How do I export import a template function

Tags: c++, c++20, function-templates, c++-modules

I have a template function, that I want to call from several .cpp files. Normally, I would have written this template function in a .h file and #include it, but I heard of C++20 modules and was curious how it could be imported / exported using this new C++20 feature.

```
//latuile_test_json_output.cpp

template <unsigned N>
void latuile_test_json_output(const vector<MyRect> &input_rectangles,
                               int (&edges)[N][2],
                               const vector<MyRect> &expected_rectangles,
                               const char* test_name,
                               int test_number)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Where is `latuile_test_json_output` defined (a header or a module unit)? Do you already have a module unit?

Comment: I was thinking of putting the implementation code in a .cpp, spare a .h, and simply export it. But I don't know how to do it with a template function.

Comment: [This chap](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-open-questions-to-modules) shows how to do so by enclosing the template(s) in an exported `namespace`.

Comment: @LudovicAubert: Does your build system support C++ modules? That's the first thing you need to check, because many build systems don't yet.

Comment: I am using g++-10, and I got: warning: keyword ‘export’ not implemented, and will be ignored. Good point :)

Answer (score 1):

Your API is C++, but is to much influenced by C style code.
This `N` template parameter is completely useless.

Since you are using C++20 just use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) and you are done:

```cpp
void latuile_test_json_output(const vector<MyRect> &input_rectangles,
                              std::span<std::array<int, 2> edges,
                              const vector<MyRect> &expected_rectangles,
                              std::string_view test_name,
                              int test_number)
{
...
}
// or if you think std::array is to much:
void latuile_test_json_output(const vector<MyRect> &input_rectangles,
                              std::span<int[2]> edges,
                              const vector<MyRect> &expected_rectangles,
                              std::string_view test_name,
                              int test_number)
{
...
}
```

In this form function is no longer a template, so no problem to export this function from dll.

Note that `std::span` has respective constructor to handle c-style arrays:
[std::span<T,Extent>::span - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span)

> template< [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) N >
> constexpr span( element_type (&arr)[N] ) noexcept; (4)

Comment: ok; since the question is how to export and import a template function; shall we edit the question to have a function that really needs to be templated? After all, your answer really doesn't answer the question for others reading this.

Comment: In C++ templates are instantiated in place of use. This means in most common cases they are not part of any target (executable). That is why they have to be in header file and they  can't be part of library. Only instantiation for specific types (parameters) of template can be part of dynamic library. That is why I've recommend you use of `std:span`.